# Routing TCP/IP through PC

Tags: c#, tcp, routes, ip, forwarding

I want to use a PC with two Ethernet ports to be connected with the local networks at the first port and a detector which uses TCP/IP over Ethernet to communicate at the second port. The following image should demonstrate the setup:

[image]

The detector is directly connected with the display over a patch cable. The display and the server are connected with the local network. But MAC-Bridging is not possible, because the display needs to communicate with the detector as well as the server, which communicates over the local network.

I'm writing the software for the display in C# and Windows Embedded 7 and want to know, how I can bridge/forward/route the incoming requests from the server(s) to the detector.

Comment: Have you tries something? Like usual socket operations : bind, select read / write ?

Comment: Assuming the display runs windows? why not just bridge the network connections?

Comment: Is this a programming question or a networking logistics question? I see that you mention you're writing some kind of program for the "display" machine, but then you diverge into a final question of passing packets between the "server" and "detector". Is there anything you have tried? I'd assume some sort of static route might work here, but it has nothing to do with C#, unless you plan to dynamically configure the machine for changes in routing entries through code.

Comment: Why would you need to do anything special? Why not just hook it up as per your diagram? It should "just work". You do not require bridging/forwarding/routing since the detector does not need to talk to the server.

Comment: OK I got it now.
First you have to enable routing at the Display. With the registry-key: HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\IPEnableRouter to 1 (defauklt is 0).
After that you have to make sure, that the "Server-" and the "Detector-Network" are different subnets.
With different subnets, you have to tell the networks where or how they can find (or should send the packets) the target subnet. I solved this with a static route on the server, under Windows this can be added via the command:
route -p add TARGETSUBNETWORK mask 255.x.x.x DisplayIpInThisNetwork